# M2-to-SATA Adapter from a Lenovo Laptop is not compatible with standard SATA connectors

Tags: ssd, sata, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo T470p which initially had a 500GB M2-into-SATA-adapter 2.5" SSD.
I bought a bigger normal SATA SSD and I mounted it into the laptop, all worked ok.

I was planning to re-use the old 500GB drive, so I bought an SATA-to-USB adapter (just to copy the data from it before I mount it in an older laptop).

**THE ISSUE**: the SATA connector from the adapter which was in the Lenovo laptop **does not fit** into the standard SATA connector from the standard adapter that I bought.

What I pulled out of the Lenovo looks like this: [image]

The connector of the SATA-to-USB adapter looks like this: [image]

Notice ***the tiny black pawl that I circled in red on both photos***; that's the reason for them not fitting.

I know for sure that the adapter (2nd photo) follows the standards, because it worked with other normal SATA 2.5" SSD that I bought some time ago.
So I'm confused about the pawl that I found in the M2-into-SATA-adapter that I pulled out from the Lenovo Laptop.

Does anybody know why this is? What solutions do I have? Am I missing something regarding the adapter types, were my expectations wrong?

Comment: You may want to check this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1322607/wide-sata-connector-with-no-break-in-the-middle; perhaps you have a NVME/SATA-express device?

Comment: Can you provide model numbers?  I suspect what you have isn't a SATA drive.

Comment: `AM12Y000400` on one side, `AM12Y000500` on the other. It seems it's like @Paul said... blimey`.... :)

Comment: Unless I'm very wrong... there's not such thing as an USB adapter for this particular SSD that I could find to buy. *AND*, I can't fit it into a laptop with standard SATA "mother" connnector. 
Good thing that the new SATA SSD still worked in the SATA-Express "mother" socket, otherwise things would've gotten really unpleasant...

Comment: @Serban SATAs successors are designed with that backwards compatibility in mind. That makes it possible to e.g. use a SATA drive on a SAS backplane.